# How can I get all IDs by grid grouping?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI grid that is populated by Ajax query to an api.
The grid has column for sample IDs, status (if document is generated or not) and a button to generate the document (if not already).

I am implementing a button to generate documents for all sampleIds in one go and need to fetch the IDs of remaining ones.

And I group the IDs based on status like this:

```
dataSource.fetch(function(){
                          var view = dataSource.view();
                          console.log(view.length);
                          console.log(view[0]);
                    });
```

I want to implement a function that gets all the IDs (with status 'F' ) and generate documents for them. How do I get this view array in the function?

I tried this but it says datasource is undefined.

```
<button id='RegenerateButton' onclick=regenerateAll()>Regenerate All</button>

function regenerateAll(){
                dataSource.fetch(function(){
                          var view = dataSource.view();
                         console.log(view.length);
                          console.log(view[0]);
                    });
            }
```

My dataSource is defined like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                var crudServiceBaseUrl = window.location.origin + "/api",
                    dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource
                    ({
                        type: "json",
                        serverPaging: true,
                        serverSorting: true,
                        serverFiltering: true,
                        allowUnsort: true,
                        pageSize: 10,
                        group:{field:"Status"},
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/HL7Message/getListOfProcessedData/",
                                dataType: "json",
            
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

The first change you will want to make is to get the data source's data ([documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/data)) and not the view.

In terms of grouping the data you will need to do the following:

1. Get the data
2. Filter the data by its status field
3. Map the data to get its id field
4. Get just the unique values from the mapped/filtered values

Here is an example:

```js
const everyId = dataSource.data()
                  .filter(row => row.Status === 'F')
                  .map(row => row.Id);
const uniqueIds = [...new Set(everyId)];
```

In terms of the datasource variable being undefined, I will need to see a bit more code. There are two possibilities I can think of:

1. You have a typo and the datasource variable is named something else
2. The datasource lives in a different context (i.e. scope) than where you're trying to access it from

Comment: David , Thanks for the response.As you can see my dataSource is initialized in the ````$(document).ready(function ()```` and I am trying to call it in another function. Is it possible to initialize it globally so that I can use it anywhere in the script tag, or do I have to make ajax call again to the api?

Comment: @schwifty - I would would make it so that your function takes a "data" argument then reference the argument value.

Comment: David, I am calling method like this
`$("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: dataSource,toolbar: [
                        "Queue Data Status",
                        { template: "<button id='RegenerateButton' onclick=regenerateAll(#=dataSource#)>Regenerate All</button>"} ,
                        "search"]`

`function regenerateAll(dataSource){
                dataSource.fetch(function(){`
Still getting error datasource undefined